# How to run shell commands in general and on startup

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, java

Beginner in Ubuntu 16.4 .
I have two commands which needs to be started when the computer starts up
Command 1: `java -jar ~/folder/abc.jar`
Command2: `~/folder/q/l32/q -p 8712`
Both of these commands workd perfectly fine from teminal.Both from the home directory.
I have created 2 bash files one with

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar ~/folder/abc.jar
```

another with

```
#!/bin/sh
~/folder/q/l32/q -p 8712
```

1. How do I run these bash files individually? Double click doesn't run them.
2. If I want these two scripts to be run at startup what I do? I modified the rc.local file and added the path of these two bash files but its not working.

Comment: rc.local runs as root after startup but before login. If your jar requires a display or your-user-related environment variables, it will fail if run before login. In 16.04 and newer, a proper systemd target is preferable to rc.local.

Comment: yes my jar would need user variable..what is systemd target?Can you explain how to do it?

Comment: That's an entirely different question, asked and answered here several times already.

Comment: Your script uses relative paths. Either cd to the appropriate directory in the script using absolute paths or use absolute paths for all the files mentioned

Comment: @muru I am using the path from home ~/q/l32/q is what I am using..so this isunlikely the problem

Comment: @yellowboy your script tells a different story

Comment: @muru it was a mistake..however now I have updated it.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @muru no its not working

Comment: Maybe you should describe what your commands are supposed to do.

Comment: The first command is a starting a db server and therefore its in a forever loop. The second command is a websocket handler. I am not sure why 'what the command would do' is important in this context?

Comment: I think you need to study how to create init.d scripts for that.

Comment: Simply add them to startup applications ***use absolute paths***, like @muru mentioned, and possibly you need a little break, depending on what the commands should do. In that case: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && command"`. In the latter case, you do not need abs path. (Dash > Startup Applications > Add).

Comment: Try adding your two lines to the `/etc/rc.local` file. Place them before `exit 0` which is the last statement in this file. Reboot your computer and see if it all works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay,so finally I did it.Let me explain the steps.

My file didn't have root access./etc/rc.local was trying to run it and was failing.As rc.local runs the file in root context.

Therefore I  switched to crontab where I can specify the file to be run with respect to which user

```
crontab -e -u myusername
```

Once inside the crobtab file i used

```
@reboot /home/username/pathToMyBashFile
```

It worked.

Answer (score 2):

All users on buntu systems have a special startup script file stored in their home directories that is read every time they log in to the system using a so-called nonlogin or interactive shell. All commands listed there are run as if they were literally typed in at the command prompt. This file is called `.bashrc` (*bash* stands for *bash shell* which is the default shell used on all buntu systems and *rc* stands for *resource configuration*). Open that file using the nano text editor like this:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

Move the cursor to the very bottom and place your commands there (not exactly sure what you are using them for):

```
java -jar abc.jar
q/l32/q -p 8712
```

Then press `ctrl + O` to save the file and `ctrl + X` to exit. Now, the next time you boot up your computer, all these commands are going to be run automatically for you.

Your first question:

```
How do I run these bash files individually?
```

You need to make them executable:

```
$ chmod a+x [FILE]
```

Then, run them from the command like by just specifying their names. For example, I've got the following script (actually, there are a million ways to run executable files at the command line):

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

Now, I need to make it executable:

```
$ chmod a+x script.sh
```

And now I can run it:

```
$ bash ./script.sh
```

Comment: The `~/.bashrc` file is read *every time an interactive bash shell is started* - not when a user logs in.

Comment: Yes I tried this...once I start the terminal the script got started.Also my first command runs forever so the second command is not executed at all. So this doesn't work.

Comment: That probably depends on the commands you're trying to run. But what I've described up here is how it's done in principle.

Comment: @misha http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: Try using absolute paths. Something like: java -jar /home/yellowboy/abc.jar (and I'm sure what the other command is and is supposed to do)

Comment: @misha the program has started in this case. But not on startup/logon. The program started once I started a terminal.Also the first command being a forever loop,the next command doesnt run,until I manually stop the program in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Pull out a terminal and edit your bashrc config file.

`$ vim ~/.bashrc`

place the line below in the bashrc. `press esc, press shift+;, enter :wq` to save the file.

`exec /path/to/file.sh && path/to/path/file2.sh`

Comment: come back to to give us response.